# Customize Update Rules for Visual Studio Applications

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, deployment, publish

We're trying to publish updates of a C# visual studio Application onto a remote server.
With well over a few hundred systems connected to a few servers, we want to keep a list of either client computer names, or client computer local IP addresses and include or exclude them from a specific publish version.

The question is, can we modify a publish configuration, other than the given tools(read, wizard) from Visual Studio, which is very limited in its configuration?

P.S. visual studio 2012 premium

Answer (score 0):

Use an instance of ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment to write yourself an updater that fixes your needs.
Wrote a more detailed explanation.. but couldn't post it because of a 9hour edit block, so sorry, I guess.